# FnLock LED as layout indicator on Thinkpad

Tags: xorg, keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb, thinkpad

Is it possible to use the FnLock/Esc LED on Thinkpad T580 as a layout switch indicator using XKB? At the moment I use CapsLock as an indicator and AltGr as a toggle key, but since capslock LED is located right on capslock key, it's usually not seen behind the hand.

```
setxkbmap -layout us,ru -option "grp:toggle,ctrl:nocaps,grp_led:caps,compose:prsc,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
```

As for FnLock, I can't find this led in /sys/class/leds:

```
$ ls /sys/class/leds/
input0::capslock  input0::scrolllock  platform::micmute  tpacpi::kbd_backlight  tpacpi::standby     tpacpi::thinkvantage
input0::numlock   phy0-led            platform::mute     tpacpi::power          tpacpi::thinklight
```

Do you have better ideas for a layout indicator?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`setxkbmap -layout us,ru -option "grp:toggle,ctrl:nocaps,grp_led:scroll,compose:prsc,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"`

Comment: Thanks, Artem, I've already tried this one. Not a single LED works then.

Comment: Do you actually have a keyboard key for Scroll Lock? Can you press the key in a text terminal (Ctrl Alt F2-F6) and see if the LED lights up?

Comment: No, there is no Scroll Lock key on Thinkpad keyboard, but Fn+K performs this function. No LED is triggered by this key.

Comment: If even the keyboard key doesn't trigger the scroll lock LED then it's most likely controlled differently. Try using https://gitlab.com/cameronnemo/brillo

Comment: But it's not even the scroll lock LED :) Its FnLock, a Thinkpad-specific indicator.